# Permission Issue: .txt file needs open in notepad ++

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have a .txt file that i moved from an old laptop to my new computer. I can open the .txt in notepad but i need to be able to open it in Notepad ++. When I try to open in Notepad ++ I get the following error message.

"You do not have permission to open this file. Please contact your administrator to obtain permission."

Anyone know of a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could right click on the file and go to properties, then click the Security tab and make sure your username has Full control of the file.

Also, you could right click on the Notepad++ shortcut and hit run as Administrator. Then from within Notepad++ open the file.